# Batch file that briefly disconnects WiFi when F10 is pressed instantly closes

Tags: batch-file, wifi

I haven't done any batch files in a longer time and aren't very good at doing them. I wanted to create one I can keep running in the background which disconnects WiFi for a short time whenever I press F10. The problem is that the command prompt always closes when I open the batch file. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
:LOOP
IF IsKeyDown(F10) GOTO DISCONNECT
goto LOOP

:DISCONNECT
netsh wlan disconnect
timeout 3
netsh wlan connect name="Piggy"
goto LOOP
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The IF statement is not a valid batch file command. Not sure where you got that code from.

Comment: @Squashman `IsKeyDown` is a static method of  `[System.Windows.Input.Keyboard]` class in .NET.

Comment: What is that `IsKeyDown()` function? Windows batch files do not have functions like that. Polling for a key press would horribly inefficient anyway. You need to write a background program using C or some other higher level language to setup a call-back or even handler for the global key press.

Comment: @JosefZ, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Newbie, you should take some lessons in writting PowerShell scripts, VB or C#.

Comment: Powershell can do this easily. Pure batch is limited.

Comment: guess i'll have to learn PowerShell then, thank you anyway ^^